# content loaded with JQuery needs form submit to reload content in parent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

Working on an admin-dashboard page, and I have it loading other pages from a nav menu with JQuery like so:

```
 $('#stores.sub_menu--link').click(function(){

    $('#content').load("https://mydomain.mywebsite.com/ApageWithForms.php")

});
```

This part works fine; the problem is this:
The loaded content is coming from PHP pages, and have form  and click GET and POST functions. These work fine if we load the page itself in a browser, but when the page is loaded as content POSTing or GETing loads the page in a new tab instead of reloading in the content. I understand WHY it does it, but I have no idea HOW to fix it! I have tried adding `_PARENT` to forms and pages even though I knew this wouldn't be the answer (it wasn't).
I've tried searching, but I think my limited ability to explain the problem is also preventing me from finding a solution.
Can anyone point me in the right direction? What I am looking to have happen is when a form is submitted have the page re-load into the dynamic location of the parent.

Comment: With jQuery one does not require any forms, to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The loaded content had duplicate class, id and names for some elements which confused jQuery. Changing these allowed ajax posts to work as intended.